# Spring Autowire returning only one object from JSON Array of objects , when reading file from class path

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am using Springboot application

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.7</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

My **JSON Structure** is below and I am reading it from a file in Classpath named: "source.json"

```
[
    {
        "id": "12345",
        "name": "Name 1",
        "key": "Key 1",
        "pdetails": "desc1"
    },
    {
        "id": "12346",
        "name": "Name 2",
        "key": "Key 2",
        "pdetails": "desc2"
    },
    {
        "id": "12347",
        "name": "Name 3",
        "key": "Key 3",
        "pdetails": "desc3"
    }
]
```

And I am using **POJO Structure**: TestPOJO.java

```
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:source.json")
@ConfigurationProperties

public class TestPOJO {
    String id;
    String name;
    String pdetails;
    String key;
    
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getPdetails() {
        return pdetails;
    }
    public void setPdetails(String pdetails) {
        this.pdetails = pdetails;
    }
    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }
    public void setKey(String key) {
        this.key = key;
    }
    
}
```

**In my Controller** I am using below code for autowire

```
@Autowired
private TestPOJO testData;
```

This code always returning only Last object of the JSON Array
***its not returning all objects.***
The output is below:

```
 [{
        "id": "12347",
        "name": "Name 3",
        "key": "Key 3",
        "pdetails": "desc3"
    }]
```

Can somebody help me what is wrong with my Code.

Comment: Have you tried to declare @ConfigurationProperties as a List<TestPOJO> ?

Comment: That's because you have a list of objects in JSON and you are autowiring a single object.

Comment: @RobertoPetrilli may i know how to declare configurationpropertis as list? could you provide a sample code.